# Difference between two ways to make a request in Express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm wondering the difference of making a request in two different ways in an Express application.

First is this, which was just how it was written it a repo I came in to:

```
http.get(options, res => {
      res.on('data', data => {
        returnValue += data;
      });

      res.on('end', () => {
        returnValue = JSON.parse(returnValue.toString());
        this.setAPIJson(returnValue);
      });
    });
```

The second is from the examples shown in Node.js documentation:

```
const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
  console.log('headers:', res.headers);

  res.on('data', (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });
});

req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});

req.end();
```

I'm just curious what the difference is between these two methods and if there's it's just stylistic or there's a benefit to doing one or the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of them are doing fundamentally different things.

The first snippet collects each data chunk, appending to a string in the `'data'` callback. The `'end'` callback is triggered when all the data has been received.

The second snippet prints each chunk and has a listener on the request object for an error. Not the response object. Notice the difference between `req` and `res`.

Comment: I more so meant the difference between all in an anonymous function vs declaring it as a variable and referencing that const

Comment: Well both of them are doing fundamentally different things. 

The first snippet collects each data chunk, appending to a string in the `'data'` callback. The 'end' callback is triggered when all the data has been received.

The second snippet prints each chunk and has a listener on the request object for an error. Not the response object. Notice the difference between `req` and `res`.

Comment: That comment would fit well in the answer if you are able to edit it.

Comment: Okay, so it’s not stylistic, there’s actually a function difference in the two. I had overlooked the req vs res .end calls. So, is it good practice to always have that ‘req.end()’ call?

Comment: Straight from the docs you were looking at. 

"In the example req.end() was called. With http.request() one must always call req.end() to signify the end of the request - even if there is no data being written to the request body."